# SQL Server native client 11.0 does not support connection to SQL Server 2000 or earlier version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to get data from a SQL Server 2000 database and insert it into another database in SQL Server 2012.

The linked server was created, but I get an error when I use `SELECT` from one of the tables.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM linked_server_name.database_name.schema.table_name
```

Error:

> SQL Server native client 11.6 does not support connection to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions

Any idea can be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing an older version of the client tools on the same machine? Alternatively try connecting via "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". And in a pinch you could use BCP utility to transfer data.

Comment: Yes Im trying "OLE DB Provider".
Thanks but Sql server 2000 doesn't support BCP utility.

Comment: According to your question you're using the "SQL Native Client Provider", not the "OLE DB Provider".

Comment: While I wouldn't emphatically claim SQL Server 2000 does support bcp because I don't have such an old version to test; I'm fairly certain I used it 'back in the day (as in first half of 2000's)'. More importantly numerous online links (including MS documentation for SQL Server 2016) state that it is supported.

Comment: According to [Microsoft SQL Server 2000 DBA Survival Guide](https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-2000-Survival-Guide/dp/0672324687) the BCP utility has been available since ***before*** SQL Server 7.0! If you're going to be blasé about suggestions and not bother to investigate them properly, why do you bother asking in the first place?

Comment: I am curious how the linked server was created if SQL Server native client 11.6 does not support connection to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

Use the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" (SQLOLEDB) OLE DB provider, not SQL Server Native Client 11.0" (SQLNCLI11) OLE DB provider to access SQL Server 2000. Although SQLOLEDB is deprecated, you'll need to use it for SQL Server 2000, which is unsupported anyway.

Comment: I assume @shubniggurath meant the "_ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions_" error which I am getting as well.

Comment: @user1451111, did you try the OLE DB provider I suggested in my answer? The legacy "SQL Server" ODBC driver in conjunction with the MSDASQL (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers) is another method but it adds additional overhead since linked servers speak OLE DB natively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it today using SQL Server 2014 on Windows 8.1 Pro. I was trying to add a Linked Server for a remote SQL Server 2000 instance. While using the ***SQL Server Native Client 11.0*** I received the same error as the OP.

Then I tried creating an ODBC data source on my machine, using "**ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server**" and got the following error. "***ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions***"

At last I created a new Data Source using "**SQL Server**" driver in the New Data Source wizard, **NOT** "*SQL Server Native Client 11.0*" driver. The Data Source was successfully created. And then I used this newly created data source as "Product name" and "Data source" both, in "New Linked Server" dialog box in the Management Studio, and selected "***Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers***" as the provider. In the "Linked server" field, I put the IP address of the remote SQL Server. It successfully created a new Linked Server in my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I hope this answer will help anyone who lands here in search of an answer for this issue.